# How can I get a headless device to connect to the Local network through Wi-Fi?

Tags: python, flutter, networking, dart, raspberry-pi

I am trying to connect a headless Raspberry pi to connect to the local Wi-Fi network out of the box. I want to `wpa_supplicant.conf` to be automated though a mobile app (Flutter app) given that the mobile is in the same network as the Raspberry pi is said to be connected to. This Flutter app will also be connected to a Firebase

Comment: IMHO best way is to use BLE channel to pass such info. This approach is superior to approach of RPI posing itself  accesspoint.